# json value not accepting special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file. I want to display values including special characters like :
`Finish.`
`"Global"`
`&`
`copyright logo`
`(note: lorem)`
`â€”`
`date format 12/3/2017`
`$100`

The issue I'm facing is when I remove all special characters it works but when I include them I get an error. Below is the Complete File i'm working with.

```
<select class="form-control col-xl-12" id="component-selected0">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var somejson = '[{\"trackMe0\":\"Meta Navigation: Primary Navigation: Global Home.\"},{\"trackMe1\":\"Getâ€” on 12/3/2017 & on 31/3/2017\"},{\"trackMe2\":\"Meta Navigation\"},{\"trackMe3\":\"Primary Navigation \\\"Global\\\" Home\"},{\"rdtextfield0\":\"Redefining global with value of $100\"}]';

var mainObject = JSON.parse(somejson);

  for (var key in mainObject) {

          var innerObject = mainObject[key];
              for (var innerKey in innerObject) {
            var t = innerObject[innerKey];
            console.log(t);

  var ud = t;
            if (ud == "" || ud == undefined){
            $('#class-selected0').closest('option').remove();
    }
    else{
  var row = document.createElement('select');
  var col2 = document.createElement('option');
    col2.value = t;
    col2.text = innerKey;
  var sel = $('#class-selected0').append(row.appendChild(col2));

  }
}
}
  return sel;
```

In console.log it is giving correctly, but in select dropdown its giving error as 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Meta Navigation: Primary Navigation, Global Home' and when i remove all special characters -- value is displayed in select dropdown. Can some one help me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:                                                                       If i remove all special characters which i have mentioned above it works

Comment: that's it? Nothing after the colon? What line of code does it point to?

Comment: It prints the whole value ex: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Meta Navigation: Primary Navigation: Global Home.

Comment: Its working fine..Check this. https://jsfiddle.net/798r1j9e/

Comment: _Alaksandar Jesus Gene i have updated my code. please check and revert back with your solution